# How do I do this jquery pattern in dart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart, promise, dart-async

I'm trying to convert the following javascript/jquery code into dart, but I'm having problems understanding how futures work.

```js
function fnA() {
    fnB().then(function() {
        // do something
    }
}

function fnB() {
   var ret = $.Deferred();

   _db.open(database_name).then(function() {
       var defers = [];

       _db.keys().forEach(function(key_name) {
          var key_dfd = $.Deferred();
          defers.push(key_dfd);
          _db.getByKey(key_name).then(function(data) {
              key_dfd.resolve(data);
          });
       });
       $.when(defers).then(ret.resolve);
   })
   .fail(function() {
       ret.reject();
   });

   return ret.promise();
}
```

I thought I could do it similar to following, but it doesn't seem to work:

(I'm using lawndart for the database)

```dart
void fnA() {
    fnB().then((_) {
        // Here, all keys should have been loaded
    });
}

Future fnB() {
    return _db.open().then((_) {
        return _db.keys().forEach((String key_name) {
             return _db.getByKey(key_name).then((String data) {
                  // do something with data
                  return data;
             });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You're not catching errors that happen in any of the `defers`!!! Do not use your own `new Deferred`, but simply return the promise that you already have…

Answer (score 1):

I made some improvments but haven't tested the code:

```dart
void fnA() {
    fnB().then((_) {
        // Here, all keys should have been loaded
    });
}

Future fnB() {
  return _db.open().then((_) {
    List<Future> futures = [];
    return _db.keys().forEach((String key_name) { 
      futures.add(_db.getByKey(key_name).then((String data) {
        // do something with data
        return data;
      }));
    }).then(() => Future.wait(futures));
  });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that wont work because when the `Future.wait` is executed, the `futures` list is empty since the forEach hasn't run yet.

Comment: That wont work either. `() =>` returns a function, not a `Future`, which is what the list wants.

Comment: () => returns a function but `.then()...` returns a `Future`

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with JavaScript/jQuery for a moment, `fnB` can (assuming compatibility of Promise implementations) be written more efficiently as follows :

```
function fnB() {
    return _db.open(database_name).then(function() {
        return $.when.apply(null, _db.keys().map(function(key_name) {
            return _db.getByKey(key_name);
        }));
    });
}
```

As far as I can tell from the Dart documentation, this should translate into Dart something like this :

```
function fnB() {
    return _db.open().then(function() {
        return Future.wait(_db.keys().map(function(key_name) {
            return _db.getByKey(key_name);
        }));
    });
}
```

*The assumption about Promise compatibility disappears on translation, but the above code assumes that `_db.keys()` returns an Array. If this assumption is not valid, then the code will be slightly different.*

`fnA` will be something like this :

```
function fnA() {
    fnB()
        .then((List values) => doSomething(values))
        .catchError((e) => handleError(e));
}
```

That's the essence of it. You may need to work at the detail.

Comment: _db.keys() returns a `Stream` so it's kind of hard to get a `List<Future>` out of it..

Comment: @Naddiseo, aha, so it's a Stream - (and Streams are awkward devils). The way I see it, the objective of `fnB` is to execute `_db.keys()`, map the returned Stream into an array (of futures) and to pass that array to `Future.wait()`. From what I read in the Dart documentation, that is essentially correct but as I said, you may need to work at the detail.