# Waiting for Futures raised by other Futures

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm using the Lawndart library to access browser data, and want to collect the results of a set of queries. Here's what I thought should work:

```dart
  numberOfRecordsPerSection(callback) {
    var map = new Map();

    db_sections.keys().forEach((_key) {
      db_sections.getByKey(_key).then((Map _section) {
        int count = _section.length;
        map[_key] = count;
      });
    }).then(callback(map));
  }
```

However, when the callback is called, `map` is still empty (it gets populated correctly, but later, after all the Futures have completed). I assume the problem is that the Futures created by the `getByKey()` calls are not "captured by" the Futures created by the `forEach()` calls.

How can I correct my code to capture the result correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code from [How do I do this jquery pattern in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554093) looks very similar to yours

For each entry of `_db.keys()` a future is added to an array and then waited for all of them being finished by `Future.wait()`

Not sure if this code works (see comments on the answer on the linked question)

```dart
void fnA() {
    fnB().then((_) {
        // Here, all keys should have been loaded
    });
}

Future fnB() {
  return _db.open().then((_) {
    List<Future> futures = [];
    return _db.keys().forEach((String key_name) { 
      futures.add(_db.getByKey(key_name).then((String data) {
        // do something with data
        return data;
      }));
    }).then((_) => Future.wait(futures));
  });
}
```

Comment: Apart from small nitpicks, it's exactly how I would solve it. There is no need to create a `new Future` for the return of the `then` call in the `add` argument, and the final `then` call needs to have a function argument, so put `(_) =>` before `Future.wait`.

Comment: Another, perhaps too clever, solution would be: `return _db.keys().map(...).fold(new Future.value(), (a, b) => a.then((_) => b)`. I expect `Future.wait` to be more efficient if there are many elements.

Comment: Thanks both for the helpful response. The solution worked after one minor change to remove an unneeded argument: `futures.add(_db.getByKey(key_name).then((String data) {`.

Comment: I just developed it here on the page. Would you please tell what change was necessary?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer - I accidentally pressed enter halfway through my comment - please see the updated version now.